# Error in initializing an app in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a **testApp** using **express.js** in a server containing **nodeJS** environment. Site is running in the **http://localhost:3000** And i have checked the output via command line -

```
curl http://localhost:3000/
```

Output-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Express</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Express</h1>
   <p>Welcome to Express</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

But i couldn't find it in my domain. It is showing an error like this -

```
Not Found
404

Error: Not Found

at /home/user/testApp/app.js:30:13
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at /home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:618:15
at next (/home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:256:14)
at Function.handle (/home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
at router (/home/user/testApp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
```

What could be the possible reason for such kind of error ?

**EDIT:**

App Structure:

```
.
app.js
bin
   www
package.json
public
    images
    javascripts
    stylesheets
        style.css 
routes
    index.js
    users.js
views
    error.jade
    index.jade
    layout.jade
```

Ngynx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name 10.10.10.15;

     location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /testApp {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean by finding domain ?

Comment: I have added a public domain for the localhost. So the things are running in the localhost are supposed to be run in the domain also.

Comment: will you please share your `.env` or `server.js` file

Comment: I have added the app structure and ngynx configuration file in the question.